# Regular expression Replace to remove numbers in prefix to the string

Tags: oracle, replace, expression

How to remove the numbers present before the string 'Tech search'?

```
'502402849 - Tech search;502489756 - world wide;123698745 - Tech search to'
```

Note:- Only 'Tech search' not before 'Tech search to'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One regex which can be used to match the numbers you want to replace is:

```
\d+\s-\sTech search;

SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE (col, '\d+\s-\sTech search(;|$)', '')
```

Test the regex here:

[**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/eX7hF2/3)

Comment: Actually i need to remove the entire string '502402849 - Tech search'?

Comment: It was partially correct.But its removing tech search from  this string also '123698745 - Tech search to'.Theme is to remove the entire string which matches exactly to '502402849 - Tech search'. Note:Numbers will vary.

Comment: @anandbaskar Updated again to match that exact string.  Your original question was not too clear.

Comment: Its not working...its giving the same result.Answer should be '502489756 - world wide;123698745 - Tech search to'

Comment: Updated again, this time using semicolon as the delimeter for the type of string you are trying to replace.

Comment: This is working fine when the string comes in first occurence with operator ';'.When the string comes at last position without operator';',Its failing.For Eg:-'502489756 - world wide;123698745 - Tech search to;502402849 - Tech search'    Answer should be:-'502489756 - world wide;123698745 - Tech search to'

Comment: Updated again to allow either semicolon or end of string to be the delimeter.

Answer (score 0):

**Query 1**:

```
WITH data ( value ) AS (
  SELECT '502402849 - Tech search;502489756 - world wide;123698745 - Tech search to'
  FROM   DUAL
)
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( value, '^\d+' ) AS out
FROM   data;
```

**Output**:

```
OUTPUT                                                         
----------------------------------------------------------------
 - Tech search;502489756 - world wide;123698745 - Tech search to
```

**Query 2**:

```
WITH data ( value ) AS (
  SELECT '502402849 - Tech search;502489756 - world wide;123698745 - Tech search to'
  FROM   DUAL
)
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( value, '\d+\s*-\s*(Tech search(;|$))', '\1' ) AS output
FROM   data;
```

**Output**:

```
OUTPUT                                                      
-------------------------------------------------------------
Tech search;502489756 - world wide;123698745 - Tech search to
```

**Query 3**:

```
WITH data ( value ) AS (
  SELECT '502402849 - Tech search;502489756 - world wide;123698745 - Tech search to'
  FROM   DUAL
)
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( value, '\d+\s*-\s*(Tech search(;|$))' ) AS output
FROM   data;
```

**Output**:

```
OUTPUT                                                      
-------------------------------------------------
502489756 - world wide;123698745 - Tech search to
```

Answer (score 0):

regexp_replace('502402849 - Tech search;502489756 - world wide;123698745 - Tech search to','\d+(?= - Tech search;)', '');